# Toggle between views

Tags: reporting-services

Good morning, I have recieved a rather odd reqeust.  I currently have a report that is grouped by weeks.  The customer loves the report but he would like a toggle option that would switch the view to months instead of weeks.  I have never recieved this kind of request before and am not certain how to do this.  Any assistance, direction, etc would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to prompt the user in the report to select a parameter on the weeks/month preference and then use an "IIF" in the group section of your table/matrix based on the parameter passed to group by the user selection (either Months or Weeks).

Comment: i will try that, not sure i totally follow what you are saying but i think i get it.  I didn't know you could do that in the matrix group.

Comment: ok, i did the above and it worked great, but now my drill down is having issues.  How would i do this: IIf(Parameters!View.Value="Week" and IIf(InScope("Week"),Fields!WeekofYear.Value,IIf(Parameters!View.Value="Month" and IIf(InScope("Week"),Fields!MonthofYear.Value, 999))))
cause that doesn't work

Comment: How about trying to use a switch instead of the IIF command?

Switch (boolean test, true, false)
Switch (Parameters!View.Value="Week", Fields!WeekofYear.Value, Fields!MonthofYear.Value)

Something along theses lines possibly?